building SkeletonPass on Windows - "Loadable modules not supported on this platform"
I'm trying to build Skeleton Pass https://github.com/sampsyo/llvm-pass-skeleton on Windows but I'm not sure if it is supported
This is not duplicate, because the other question asks about Linux
Here's my files structure
D:.
│   .gitignore
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   LICENSE
│   README.md
│
├───build
└───skeleton
CMakeLists.txt
Skeleton.cpp

And here's my cmake script
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)
project(Skeleton)

# LLVM uses C++17.
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(LLVM_HOME D:/LLVM/llvm-project/llvm/build)
set(LLVM_DIR ${LLVM_HOME}/lib/cmake/llvm)

# Load LLVMConfig.cmake. If this fails, consider setting `LLVM_DIR` to point
# to your LLVM installation's `lib/cmake/llvm` directory.
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

# Include the part of LLVM's CMake libraries that defines
# `add_llvm_pass_plugin`.

include(AddLLVM)

# Use LLVM's preprocessor definitions, include directories, and library search
# paths.
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})
include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${LLVM_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# Our pass lives in this subdirectory.
add_subdirectory(skeleton)

For some reason I see this problem:

SkeletonPass ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.

cmake ..
-- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22000.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.40.33811.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: H:/VS/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: H:/VS/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.40.33807/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- SkeletonPass ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.
-- Registering SkeletonPass as a pass plugin (static build: OFF)
-- Configuring done (5.8s)
-- Generating done (0.1s)
-- Build files have been written to: D:/LLVM/passes/1/llvm-pass-skeleton/build

What's going on?
I've tried this, LLVM out of source pass build: Loadable modules not supported (on Linux), but there are other issues too:
-- Looking for os_signpost_interval_begin - not found
-- SkeletonPass ignored -- Loadable modules not supported on this platform.

Is the message "Loadable modules not supported on this platform" not clear?

@JesperJuhl it is, but I dont believe that there's no way to make it work on Windows
